# Ruby - Open3 not finishing subprocess

Tags: ruby, child-process, popen3

I'm using:

```
- Ruby 1.9.3-p448
- Windows Server 2008
```

I have a file that contains commands that is used by a program, I'm using it in this way

```
C:\> PATH_TO_FOLDER/program.exe file.txt
```

`File.txt` have some commands so `program.exe` will do the following:

```
- Execute commands 
- Reads from a DB using an ODBC method used by program
- Outputs result in a txt file
```

Using powershell this command works fine and as expected.

Now I have this in a file (`app.rb`):

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'open3'

get '/process' do
  program_path = "path to program.exe"
  file_name = "file.txt"
  Open3.popen3(program_path, file_name) do |i, o, e, w|
    # I have some commands here to execute but just as an example I'm using o.read
    puts o.read
  end
end
```

Now when using this by accessing `http://localhost/process`, `Open3` works by doing this (I'm not 100% sure but after trying several times I think is the only option)

- Reads commands and executes them (this is ok)
- Tries to read from DB by using ODBC method (Here is my problem. I
  need to receive some output from `Open3` so I can show it in a browser, but I guess when it tries to read it starts another process that `Open3` is not aware of, so Open3 goes on and finish without waiting for it)
- Exits

Exits

I've found about following:

- Use `Thread.join` (in this case, `w.join`) in order to wait for process to finish, but it doesn't work
- `Open4` seems to handle child process but doesn't work on Windows
- `Process.wait(pid)`, in this case `pid = w.pid`, but also doesn't work
- `Timeout.timeout(n)`, the problem here is that I'm not sure how long
  will it take.

Is there any way of handling this? (waiting for `Open3` subprocess so I get proper output).

Comment: What is the significance of URL `http://localhost/process`?

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem getting the exit status and this is what we did

```
Open3.popen3(*cmd) do |stdin, stdout, stderr, wait_thr|

  # print stdout and stderr as it comes in
  threads = [stdout, stderr].collect do |output|
    Thread.new do
      while ((line = output.gets rescue '') != nil) do
        unless line.blank?
          puts line
        end
      end
    end
  end

  # get exit code as a Process::Status object
  process_status = wait_thr.value #.exitstatus

  # wait for logging threads to finish before continuing
  # so we don't lose any logging output
  threads.each(&:join)

  # wait up to 5 minutes to make sure the process has really exited
  Timeout::timeout(300) do
    while !process_status.exited?
      sleep(1)
    end
  end rescue nil

  process_status.exitstatus.to_i
end
```

Comment: I tried this, the problem is that inside block when I print "w.value.exited?" it returns true... so Open3.popen3(program_path, file_name) actually finishes, what seems not to finish is the child process of it (I'm just guessing)

Comment: memo is defined as "memo = []" or is it something else?. I got undefined variable error for it

Comment: I extracted this from some other code so I might have missed a few things. I corrected that one

Comment: There is no `blank?` in Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Open3.popen3` is easy only for trivial cases. I do not know the real code for handling the input, output and error channels of your subprocess. Neither do I know the exact behaviour of your subprocesses: Does it write on stdout? Does it write on stderr? Does it try to read from stdin?

This is why I assume that there are problems in the code that you replaced by `puts o.read`.
A good summary about the problems you can run into is on http://coldattic.info/shvedsky/pro/blogs/a-foo-walks-into-a-bar/posts/63.

Though I disagree with the author of the article, Pavel Shved, when it comes to finding a solution. He recommends his own solution. I just use one of the wrapper functions for `popen3` in my projects: `Open3.capture*`. They do all the difficult things like waiting for stdout and stderr *at the same time*.